# Book recommendations for the design and analysis of clinical trials for drug development

Tags: references, experiment-design, clinical-trials

I am looking for some recommendations for books about the statistical analysis of clinical trials data, that also covers the design of clinical trial studies. I am familiar with Stephen Senn's book, "Statistical Issues in Drug Development", although I only have the 1st edition.

Comment: *Statistical Principles for Clinical Trials* published by the International Conference on Harmonisation would be a good start. And it's free.

Comment: This might provide a good intro reference https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat509/